# Connection Google Data Studio to Azure MySql database

Tags: mysql, azure, looker-studio

I am trying to connect to a MySql database hosted on Azure
I have Whitelisted the IPs: 142.251.74.0- 142.251.74.23 and 74.125.0.0 - 74.0.0.16

I can connect to this Database using DBeaver and my website, so I know it's not a credentials issue.
This is the error I get upon trying to connect using the MySql connector in Data Studio...
Can't connect to the database. Please double check your connection parameters. Learn more about database connectors here.
Error ID: 6a7dbda7

thanks,
brad

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to connect to a MySql database hosted on Azure through Google data studio

**A direct connection between Google Data Studio and Azure cannot be made at the moment.**

The following are the supported datasets to [Google data studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6283323?hl=en):

- Databases, including BigQuery and PostgreSQL
- Google Marketing Platform products, including Google Ads, Analytics, Display & Video 360, Search Ads 360
- Google consumer products, such as Sheets, YouTube, and Search Console
- Flat files via CSV file upload and Google Cloud Storage
- Social media platforms such as Facebook, Reddit, and Twitter
- Blended data from any combination of related sources